# Does MapKit offer position/scale controls?

Tags: ios, mapkit

Does the iOS 7.1+ SDK Mapkit offer Map Controls like the one in the image?

... or is this only covered via the gestures?

Are the controls exclusive to the google sdk?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**No.** MapKit doesn't include controls like the ones illustrated.

`MKMapView` (the map view in MapKit) typically uses touch gestures to adjust the scale and position of the map. You can pinch in/out to zoom out/in, and you can pan to adjust the displayed area.

There's nothing to prevent you from adding your own controls to a map view if you want to, but given the touch interface it's hard to see why that would be necessary. Indeed, even Google doesn't use those controls in its [Google Maps app](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/google-maps/id585027354?mt=8&ei=c_tHU8eRO6bx0gH_toCQAg&usg=AFQjCNEMo8V21rKG52EDBal5WJ0CoFLoHQ&sig2=OxEe5q_U00mVdiIvS8ezYQ&bvm=bv.64542518,d.dmQ).